# Cannot identify mathematical approach

Tags: vectors, inner-products

I know the question is in a techninal context, but my main problem is the mathematical approach behind it. Hopefully I am right here with my question.

I just read a way to implement a recommendation system but I don't really unterstand the mathematical approach behind it ([link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/08/beginners-guide-learn-content-based-recommender-systems/)).

The author uses three vectors to generate a prediction for a item. In his last image example he uses the "SUMPRODUCT"-function from Microsoft Excel which just build the sum of the products from his three vectors. He explain it mathematically as simple dot product, but is it true? I thought a dot product like this is only for two vectors possible. I know, it exist the triple product method, but in this case he would need the cross product of two vectors. Is here any mathematical approach to legitimize/explain this technique?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

Comment: It's actually explained in the article: "The dot product of article vectors and IDF vectors gives us the weighted scores of each article.These weighted scores are again used for a dot product with the user profile vector (user 1 here)." This is not the dot product of three vectors, this is just calculating a weight vector, via product of each coordinate, and after that making the dot product with the vector of the user (which I guess it gives you the information you want).

Comment: @AnilCh Thank you! But is multiplying each coordinate of both vectors a valid form to calculate a new weight vector? I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: @Jason That's a good question, but it's not a mathematical one. In mathematics this product is called "Hadamard product" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices) ), and it is a valid operation in vectors and matrices. But you'd need to be sure that it actually makes sense in your problem, which needs you to know what these vectors represent. I don't know enough to answer with confidence about this problem, but they seem to be some kind of frequency vectors, so it would make sense to obtain weights by making their products.

Comment: @AnilCh You are a bless. The article vectors contain the term frequencies (TF) for all terms for each article. The IDF vector instead contains all inverse document frequencies for the terms. Then I look how to calculate a TF-IDF (which stands for a weighted term)(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) it shows a simple multiplication of the term frequency and inverse document frequency. When I present them as vectors the Hadamard product should make sense in this case, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jason yeah, that's it